# Windows 7 command prompt processes run twice in separate instances

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface

Whenever I launch a command prompt process from the command prompt, I expect everything to happen within that command prompt.  It used to.

Now, for some reason, instead it does this:

- launches a second command prompt instance
- executes there
- the second command prompt disappears
- the app runs as expected in the original command prompt

In other words, first this...

[image]

...then this...

[image]

At first I thought it was a problem with `grep` but any console app does this - even debugging in Visual Studio. ***EDIT:*** Debugging (F5) actually works as expected, but launching directly (Ctrl+F5) behaves as described above - I hope this new clue helps someone point me where to look - I have no more hair to pull out :-)

Even stranger:  if I run, say, `start grep -ild foobar *.txt` it launches in a second window (as expected) then a second time when the first time is done.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Can't say for sure but it sounds like a word file association issue. Maybe check to see if .exe has any strange file association setting?

Comment: What happens when you run an internal command, such as `DIR *.*`?

Comment: @Twisty internal commands no problem.  Weirder: xcopy.exe no problem.

Comment: Is the command actually *running twice* or is the output from the second window simply appearing (being transferred or *whatever* the heck is happening) back to the first window?

Comment: It is actually running twice.  I like using grep because at least the second run doesn't matter.  This really sucks when I'm running a console app that writes to a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!  It was Avast virus scanner's Deep screen option.  I disabled it (Avast UI->Settings->Antivirus->Enable DeepScreen [uncheck]).

I'll have to read up what risk this exposes, and whether I can fine tune it - but at least now the annoyance is over :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a setting in the [Autorun](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/21/6447771.aspx) registry value for the Command Prompt. If so, the content of this registry value will be executed each time you run a command in Command Prompt.

Have a look at the Registry path `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and look for a value named `AutoRun`.  If you have such a value, rename it to `AutorunDISABLED` and then open a new Command Prompt window and try your commands again.

Comment: That value isn't there (I didn't know about that key -thanks!).  I'm searching through the registry for anything like Autorun.

Comment: Oops, I awarded the bounty to this accidentally.  Oh well... enjoy - and thanks for taking the time :-)

Comment: Well that's no good! If you have another question you want a bounty set on, post a comment here (don't forget the @Twisty) and I'll put a +50 bounty on it. Offer stands until you need it.

Comment: @biscuit314 Well that's no good! If you have another question you want a bounty set on, post a comment here (don't forget the @Twisty) and I'll put a +50 bounty on it. Offer stands until you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your considerate offer.  I wouldn't worry about it, though - it's really no biggie.